# Why does Enum.GetValues() requires a type as argument?

Tags: c#

```
enum Day { Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday };
foreach (int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Day)))
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

I know this is the way the method was specified. But why does it require the type of the enumerator instead of the enumerator? Such as:

```
Enum.GetValues(Day)
```

Was it simply a design choice?

Comment: I guess because you are querying the type and not an instance. You are checknig what are the values of the enum type - so you want a type

Comment: What do you mean by 'the enumerator object' ? What does the alternative syntax you're thinking of look like?

Comment: Do you mean `new Day().GetValues()`? That's worse than `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Day))`. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I assume you're asking why C# doesn't just let you use `Day.GetValues()`. That was a design choice, but probably a sensible one - because otherwise you would prevent the use of an enum value called `GetValues` without having some horrible kludge.

Comment: What I meant with "instead of the enumerator object" was "Enum.GetValues(Day)"

Comment: Well that's because just using the name of a type in C# (particularly as a method parameter) doesn't give you the `Type` object for that type - so that's why. `Enum.GetValues()` is just a normal C# method.